# Data load properly when I reload the page and clear cache. In chrome I have to use Ctrl + Shift + R

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created an angularjs site. I have a CRUD functionality made it with PHP. When I create an user and redirect to the home page where I have a table where the users are listed, the results show don't show me the right data, but when I hit Ctrl + Shift + R, the data shows perfect.
I'm going crazy with this issue. The database is correct. The data insert perfect in the database. I tried with a get request with postman and the data is good too. Maybe a server issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is some issues with caching, try to add timestamp to request like this
api/users?t=213124123

Comment: Yes!!!!!! That trick did the work! Thanks mate!